# Laravel : Trouble when trying to navigate till root of records

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a table category with a field category_id which tells what's the father category.

I want to navigate from the actual category till the root.

```
$category = Category::where('id', '=', $id)->first();
$tc = $category;
$cc = [];

while ($tc->category_id > 0) {
    $tc = Category::where('category_id', '=', $tc->category_id)->first();
    $cc[] = $tc;
}
```

If the line have a category_id=0 (root) then it works but if it have one, then it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `belongsTo` relationship and something like this:

```
// Category model
public function parent()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('Category', 'category_id');
}

public function getRootCategory()
{
  if ($this->hasParent()) return $this->parent->getRootCategory();

  return $this;
}

protected function hasParent()
{
  return ($this->category_id > 0);
}
```

Then all you need is:

```
$category = Category::find($someId);

$root = $category->getRootCategory();

// and all the ancestors of $category are accessible this way:
$category->parent;

$category->parent->parent;
```

Basically you don't need to use `getRootCategory` to load all the ancestors, you can simply use dynamic property (`$category->parent`) until you reach the root. It's just a convenient way to return the root cat itself.

Comment: I agree with you Mike but as you have less points than him ans your code helped ùe tpp,  I gave you the point :)

Answer (score 1):

In you model, be sure to define the parent-child relationship, something like this:

```
class Category
{
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Category', 'category_id', 'id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Category', 'id', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to query for all the category children something like so:

```
$children = Category::with('children')->find($id);
```

Comment: Keys order in `belongsTo` is wrong. It's `belongsTo(Model, foreignKey, primaryKey)`

Comment: The same goes for has many: `hasMany(Model, foreignKey, primaryKey)`